# How do I uppercase part of a date format - angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
{{main.featured.date | date:'EEEE, MMMM d, yyyy'}}
//Wednesday, March 16, 2016

//But I want: WEDNESDAY, March 16, 2016
```

Is there any way to do this without writing my own filter?

Comment: I've added an example to see my code in action.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the built-in [uppercase](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/uppercase) filter. All you need to do is split the date into two, like this: `{{(vm.myDate | date : 'EEEE, ' | uppercase) + (vm.myDate | date : 'MMMM d, yyyy')}}`

Here's an working example:

```js
(function() {
  angular
    .module('myApp', [])
    .controller('MainCtrl', function() {
      var vm = this;

      vm.myDate = new Date().getTime();
    });
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="MainCtrl as vm">
    Current date: {{ (vm.myDate | date : 'EEEE, ' | uppercase) + (vm.myDate | date : 'MMMM d, yyyy') }}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This will display WEDNESDAY, MARCH 16, 2016, but he wants: WEDNESDAY, March 16, 2016.

Comment: That's why I splited it into two expressions. The first one shows the uppercased date and the second one the rest.

Comment: Ah sorry I see now how you used it!